# SSH Login Not Working

Tags: pi-3b+, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I have an SSH server running on my PI.

On my other device I run `ssh ucyt5040@localhost -p8022`.
It asks for a password.
I enter my password. I get `Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive)`.

I've tried changing my password many times from the configuration GUI.

It never works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> On my other device I run ssh ucyt5040@localhost

localhost is the network address of the machine you are using.

You need to give the network address (by name or IP address) of the Raspberry Pi running the SSH server.

Comment: Both devices are on the same network. Why would I need to do that?

Comment: @UCYT5040 For the same reason, you don't ring your doorbell to get someone to answer the neighbor's door.  You are both on the same street/neighborhood but only one communicates to the neighbor. Or You wouldn't mail a letter to your address expecting your neighbor to receive it.